# Unsupported operand type in sum function of array

Tags: python

I am a beginner in python and i am here confused why sum function isn't working on adding array elements here is the code below `from **future**

```
inc = 0
array = []
i=0
while True:
rating=input("Enter your rate between (1 to 5) ")
inc += 1
array.insert(inc,rating)  
length = len(array)
print('total number of rating:',length)
ans = sum(array)
average = ans/length
print('avrage ratiing',round(average, 1))
while i<length:
     print(array)
     break`
```

please help

[here is the traceback](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hJ1jW.png)

Comment: What does "not working" mean? Do you get an error - please include the full traceback? It's hard to understand the code currently because the indentation is off - please fix that.

Comment: i just put the trace back please take a look now

Comment: Don't post images of errors/tracebacks. Copy and paste them

Comment: Enter your rate between (1 to 5) 3
total number of rating: 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "insert.py", line 14, in <module>
    ans = sum(a)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'

Comment: [How can I read inputs as integers?](//stackoverflow.com/q/20449427)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I read inputs as integers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20449427/how-can-i-read-inputs-as-integers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add int casting

```
rating = int(input("Enter your rate between (1 to 5) "))
```

When you get an input from the user, you get it as type of `str`.

In order to increment this number, you can cast it to `int` and than you can apply math operations.

**In Addition:**

You can add a functionality that checks that the user actually inserted a number by:

```
def get_number():
  try:
   return int(input("Enter your rate between (1 to 5) "))
  except ValueError:
   raise ValueError("That's not an integer, please insert an integer")
```

And than:

```
rating = get_number()
```

**EDIT:**

Notice that if you want to get input like '3.7' you should use `float` casting.

```
return float(input("Enter your rate between (1 to 5) "))
```

Comment: Your `get_number` function returns `None` on failure which will just cause an error later on. It's better to either retry or `except ValueError: print(...); return get_number()` or reraise the error `raise`? It'll also tell me that `3.14` is "not a number".

Comment: Sure, Added it. Thanks

Comment: @FHTMitchell, That depends whether he wants an integer input or a float input. Anyway, i've showed him how to get an input like 3.7 by using the `float` casting. Also changes the text to integer instead of number in case of `int` casting.

Comment: i also have another small programe can you check this oyt

Comment: here the error is "relab = float(1/2(fairness + (1-(score) - goodness)/2))
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable"

Comment: @Roasted_Ginger , You forgot the operand between `1/2` and the rest of your expression. `float(1/2 ?Insert operand in here? (fairness + (1-(score) - goodness)/2)) `

Comment: Thanks i am really noob -_-

Answer (score 1):

The sum function is, effectively, defined like so

```
def sum(iterable, start=0):
    total = start
    for item in iterable:
        total += item
    return total
```

Currently, your `array` is a list of strings, because that is what is returned by `input`, so the sum function tries to add a string `item` to an integer `total` giving the error

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
```

The trick is to cast the string to an int

```
rating = int(input("Enter your rate between (1 to 5) "))
```

Comment: Thanks sir and what about indents it is wasting my enough time